# Pass extJs Grid Value to Store PHP Script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, extjs

I currently have a simple extJS Grid which is pulling data from a server and presenting it to the viewer. I would like to grab the value of the selected row, and then pass it to another PHP script for processing in order to display the results in another grid.

```
var roleInformationStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  autoLoad: true,
  autoSync: true,
  model: 'RoleInformation',
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'data.php',
    reader: {
      type: 'array',
    },
    writer: {
      type: 'json'
 }
}
});

var roleInformationGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
  store: roleInformationStore,
  width: '100%',
  height: 200,
  title: 'Roles',
  columns: [
  {
    text: 'Name',
    flex: 1,
    width: 100,
    sortable: false,
    hideable: false,
    dataIndex: 'role'
 }
 ],
 listeners: {
   cellclick: function(view, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
     roleInformationStore.proxy.extraParams = record.get('role');
    //Ext.Msg.alert('Selected Record', 'Name: ' + record.get('role'));
   }
 }
});
```

Using the listener in the current grid, I am able to get the value and show it using the alert method. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, `extraParams` has to be an object of key-value string pairs, because an URI has to be something like `data.php?key1=value1&key2=value2`.

Style-wise, Sencha advises to use getters and setters, whenever possible.

Together, you get:

```
var store = Ext.getStore("roleInformationStore");
store.getProxy().setExtraParam("myRoleParamKey",record.get('role'));
store.load();
```

In PHP, you would get the parameter then using

```
$role = $_GET['myRoleParamKey'];
```

You can of course substitute `myRoleParamKey` for any alphanumeric literal you want, but make sure you use the same key on both server and client side. ;-)

Docs: [`setExtraParam`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Server.html#method-setExtraParam)

Comment: This perfect and concise. Thank you. One last thing, if I wanted to grab the value of a Grid row on a button click, would I just pass the parameter I get from that Click, to the setExtraParam parameter?